# Extending vector bundles on divisors

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles

Let $X$ be a smooth variety. Let $Y$ be the union of the four sub-varieties of $X\times \mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$ determined by $X \times \mathbb{P}^1 \times \{0\}$, $X \times \mathbb{P}^1 \times \{\infty\}$, $X \times \{0\} \times \mathbb{P}^1$ and $X \times \{\infty\} \times \mathbb{P}^1$. Can any vector bundle on $Y$ be extended to $X\times \mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$? (What are minimum requirements for this to be possible?)

2nd question: A similar question can be asked by replacing $\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$ by $\mathbb{P}^2$ and instead of 4 lines we can consider three general projective lines in $\mathbb{P}^2$ and product of them with $X$. What is the answer for the extensions problem in this scenario? What are the obstructions for the extensions?

The answer to the 1st and 2nd question seems to be negative by the comment below.

3rd question: Now assume the same question but $\mathbb{P}^1$ replaced by $\mathbb{A}^1$. The obstructions for the extensions (This is probably true if we assume $X$ is affine and believe in Bass-Quillen conjecture and assume that going around the loop gives the identity as the automorphism)

Comment: What do you mean by "extended"? $Y$ is not contained in $X$.

Comment: This already fails for line bundles if $X$ is a point: you can glue any $\mathcal O_{\mathbf P^1}(d_i)$ to each other along a square of $\mathbf P^1$s, but to come from $\mathbf P^1 \times \mathbf P^1$ the restriction to the two vertical lines (or the two horizontal lines) has to be the same. Another thing you can do is create a loop of trivial line bundles where you glue each consecutive pair by a constant such that the product around the loop is not equal to $1$.

Comment: @ abx I fixed the problem.

Comment: For $\mathbf A^1$ the situation is no different: a loop (triangle, square, ...) of $\mathbf A^1$s has nontrivial line bundles obtained from trivial line bundles on each component by glueing them using a set of constants whose product does not equal $1$.

Comment: @R. van Dobben de Bruyn For the $\mathbb{A}^1$ case is it possible to give an obstruction for the extension? (When $X$ is affine I think probably the automorphism constructed by going around the loop needs to be identity in order to be extendable)